# CPU stuck in energy save mode

Tags: performance, cpu

A few days ago, my computer started feeling *very* slow, and looking a CPU usage, I saw that even the simplest processes required a lot of CPU.

As far as I can tell, it's because the core are all down-clocked to 800Mhz, and won't up-clock again when it's needed.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cpu MHz     : 800.000
```

As a test, I then start up BOINC, to load all my cores to the max, using htop, I see all cores running at > 95%.

My cpu scaling settings:

```
$ for governor in $(ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor); do cat $governor; done
ondemand
ondemand
ondemand
ondemand
```

With 'ondemand, I expect the core to clock up, and go to full power, but a `watch` shows them steady on 800.

To get better performance, I need to manually force it:

```
sudo bash -c 'for governor in $(ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor); do
  echo"performance" > $governor;
done'
```

Whch immediately changes the frequency to:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 2701.000
cpu MHz     : 2701.000
cpu MHz     : 2701.000
cpu MHz     : 2701.000
```

Comment: Is ignore_nice_load set to 1?  Try using `stress` to simulate cpu load.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score -1):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz` (or `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`) will only show you the standard clock speeds.

If you want live CPU frequency settings, you need something a little beefier. I know `powertop` works but for a something convenient all the time, `indicator-cpu` could be worth it:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
indicator-cpufreq
```

You'll need to add `indicator-cpufreq` to the things to run at start-up, or you'll have to run it manually each login.

Comment: Actually when I installed indicator-cpufreq from the normal repos it added itself to the start-up items. I didn't have to do it manually. Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Ok, I looked in powertop since I already had it installed, and I still see essentially 0% in the higher frequencies, even when I load all cores to 100%.

Comment: No, it shows the current clock speeds, as you can see from the different values he posted in the question.